# Is it possible to block a thread until AtomicBoolean contains a desired value?

Tags: java, concurrency

I've got a system with many writers and a single reader, each running in a separate thread. The writers notify the reader when work is available, and the reader blocks until it is notified.

Given the number of writers, I want to use a lock-free implementation to notify the reader. Every time the reader wakes up, it resets the notification flag, does some work, and blocks waiting for more notifications to arrive.
Essentially I'm looking for the equivalent of an `AtomicBoolean` with an ability to block until its value becomes true.

What I've tried so far:

- My current implementation uses a `Semaphore`.
- The semaphore starts out with no permits.
- The reader blocks trying to acquire a permit.
- Writers invoke `Semaphore.release()` in order to notify the reader.
- The reader invokes `Semaphore.drainPermits()`, does some work, and blocks again on `Semaphore.acquire`.

What I don't like about the `Semaphore` approach:

- It seems a bit heavy-handed. I only care about about the first notification arriving. I don't need to keep a count of how many other notifications came in.
- Semaphores throw an exception if their count surpasses `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. This is more of a theoretical problem than practical but still not ideal.

Is there a data structure that is equivalent to `AtomicBoolean` with an ability to block waiting on a particular value?

Alternatively, is there a thread-safe manner to ensure that `Semaphore`'s number of permits never surpass a certain value?

Comment: Perhaps a `BlockingQueue<Singleton>`, just representing "go ahead" tokens?  (The direct answer to your question is "no, you can't wait on an `AtomicBoolean`.")

Comment: Probably [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mihe `CountDownLatch` cannot be reset and I don't see how `CyclicBarrier` would work in my case since I don't want to block writers.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think I just stumbled upon an interesting approach: Borrow the idea behind of `Semaphore.drainPermits`. I can override the implementation of `Semaphore.release()` to ensure its count never goes above one.

Comment: That sounds difficult to do safely, though you can probably make something good enough...

Comment: @Gili Good point.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The implementation of `Semaphore.Sync.drainPermits()` looks easy to adapt. The problem is that `Sync` is package-private so realistically speaking I'd need to copy/paste the entire `Semaphore` implementation in order to modify a single line of code...

Comment: Why do you want a lock-free implementation?  This seems like exactly what Condition.await/signal and Object.wait/notify are for.

Comment: @VGR `Condition.signal()` requires one to hold an exclusive (write) lock. As far as I can tell, the `Lock/Condition` mechanism is optimized for few writers, many readers. I assume (maybe incorrectly) that when the number of writers is very high and there is only one reader, you would be better off with a lock-free implementation.

Comment: All of the blocking classes in java.util.concurrent use a Lock or synchronization anyway.  You are likely to get better performance using [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) directly.

Comment: What are the writer actually writing? Is this flagging some state that has changed outside your Java process, signaling the reader to callback for some data within the application or what? I'm having trouble understanding how "writers" can write safely (from a visibility standpoint) without the necessary notification already.

Comment: @erickson Imagine a scenario where the reader can process data from multiple queues. It wants to block until one of the queues has data to be processed, but it cannot block on an individual queue because then it would miss notifications from the others. I hope this clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 1):

[`BlockingQueue<Singleton>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) would do this adequately.

You would create, for example, an [`ArrayBlockingQueue<Singleton>(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), and then your waiter would look like:

```
queue.take();
```

… and the notifier would look like:

```
queue.offer(Singleton.INSTANCE)
```

… with the use of `offer` ensuring that multiple releases are combined together.

Comment: Well played! Thank you :)

Comment: Honestly, I had about three _Kotlin_ suggestions off the top of my head, but doing this in Java required a little more work...

Comment: Solomon Slow correctly points out that `ArrayBlockingQueue` is not actually a lock-free implementation so I can't accept it as an answer. The search continues.

Comment: What are the precise parameters of lock-freeness for you?  Do you expect the waiter to be on a listener and not blocking?  Is it blocking, or locking, that you cannot tolerate?  (I am unconvinced that `Semaphore` does not lock by the definition you're aiming for.)

Comment: I expect the reader to block (parked thread) and writers to signal that data is ready using CAS-style techniques. Meaning, the writers never acquire a lock, but rather keep on trying to write until they succeed. As far as I can tell, `Semaphore` does exactly this under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: The Java language includes a general mechanism for threads to await arbitrary events caused by other threads. It's rather primitive, and in many applications, you'd be better off using some higher-level, problem-specific tool such as `BlockingQueue`, `CompletableFuture`, `CountdownLatch`, etc. But, for those problems where the higher-level classes all "feel a bit heavy-handed," the `Object` class has [`object.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()), [`object.notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()), and [`object.notifyAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()).*

The idea is,

- You have some `test()` that yields a `boolean` result,
- There is a `mutex` that threads are required to own when performing the test or changing its result, and
- There is at least one thread that needs to wait until the test yields `true` before it can proceed.

```java
final Object mutex = new Object();
public boolean test() { ... }
public boolean procedureThatAffectsTheTestResult() { ... }
public boolean procedureThatRequiresTestResultToBeTrue() { ... }
```

A thread that needs to wait until the test result is true can do this:

```java
synchronized (mutex) {
    while (! test()) {
        try {
            mutex.wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ...use your shameful imagination here...
        }
    }
    procedureThatRequiresTestResultToBeTrue();
}
```

Any thread that can change the test result should do it like so:

```java
synchronized (mutex) {
    procedureThatAffectsTheTestResult();
    mutex.notifyAll();   //or, mutex.notify() *IF* you know what you are doing.
}
```

The `mutex.notifyAll()` call will wake up every thread that happens to be sleeping in a `mutex.wait()` call at that same moment. `mutex.notify()` is trickier, but it will improve the performance of some applications because it will arbitrarily choose *just one* thread if more than one is waiting.

You may be wondering how a thread could ever enter a `synchronized (mutex)` block to change the `test()` result when another thread already is `wait()`ing inside another `synchronized (mutex)` block. The secret is that `mutex.wait()` temporarily unlocks the `mutex` while it is waiting, and then it guarantees to re-lock the mutex before returning or throwing an exception.

For a more complete description of when and why and how to use this feature, see the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

---

* You can also do practically the same thing using a [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) object and a [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), but that's a topic for another day.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, but I don't want writers to hold a lock in order to notify the readers because there are so many of them (and holding an exclusive lock might lead to a lot of contention).

Comment: @Gili, You Accepted Louis Wasserman's answer. But FYI, an `ArrayBlockingQueue` will require the writers to lock some kind of a mutex. It could be an actual `synchronized` block, or a `ReentrantLock`, or some hidden, unsupported low-level thing, but however it works, if writers are in contention to add to the queue, then they _will_ be blocked. I _personally_ don't know of any way that you can let the reader thread block, waiting for the flag to be set, but which does also block writers when they all pile on at the same time, trying to set it.

Comment: You are right. I will un-accept his answer. Thank you for pointing this out. As far as I can tell, `Semaphore` remains the only lock-free way to implement this.

Comment: @Gili, You've prompted me look at OpenJDK source code. The `offer(...)` method of `ArrayBlockingQueue` does in fact lock a mutex. Always. `Semaphore` on the other hand, is based on an [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/16/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html). I think the `release()` method _might_ be non-blocking—it calls the synchronizer's `compareAndSetState(...) method—but the code is convoluted, and I don't have any more time to spend looking for a definite answer. Good luck!